Problem restoring resx file values after updating Visual Studio to Version 17.11.1
After updating Visual Studio to Version 17.11.1 (and 17.11.0), resx files only return Neutral value and not other languages.
I have two different assemblies for resx files, one is general and the other is specific to a specific project (each of which has different resx files in Farsi and English languages)

These codes were working properly before the update, but now they have a problem and only return English, which is the main language.
Program.cs:
builder. Services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = Path.Combine("Resources", "Common"));
builder. Services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = Path.Combine( "1.Core", "ContentService", "Resources"));

app. UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "fa-IR", "en-US" };
    options. SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        . AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        . AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
        . ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders = true;
});

For testing, I also got help from the fluent validation library that I have used for errors in my project, but it only returns Persian language even when I set the Content-Language value to en-US to header request. This library was working properly before the update.
It was working properly before I updated but not now, does anyone know how to fix the problem or has anyone encountered this problem after the update?
Friends, if you also have the problem, please up vote this discussion.

I tested it in the old version and the latest version of VS 2022, and everything worked fine. I didn't encounter the same situation as you. I wonder if you made some modifications or installed some plug-ins after the version update. I suggest you create an additional small project to test whether you still encounter this problem. The steps I used are as follows, you can refer to them:
1: Create a new project: Select the "ASP.NET Core Web API" template and click "Next". In the Additional information window, make sure the "Enable Docker" and "Configure for HTTPS" options are unchecked.
2: Add a .resx file: In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project name, create a new folder called Resources, and then add a subfolder called Common under the Resources folder. Right-click on the Common folder and select "Add" -> "New Item", select "Resource File", and name it Errors.resx. Click "Add". Do the same and create Errors.fa-IR.resx. Fill in the key values for the two resx files accordingly.


3: Configure the localization service: Open the Program.cs file and paste the following code:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder. Services.AddLocalization();
builder. Services.AddControllers();
builder. Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder. Services.AddSwaggerGen(); Add a Swagger build service
var app = builder. Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app. Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app. UseSwagger(); Enable Swagger middleware
    app. UseSwaggerUI(); Enable the Swagger UI middleware
}
 
app. UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "fa-IR", "en-US" };
    options. SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        . AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        . AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});
app. UseAuthorization();
app. MapControllers();
app. Run();

4: Create a class called Errors, which can be placed anywhere appropriate, such as under the Resources folder:
namespace LocalizationTest.Resources.Common
{
    public class Errors
    {
    }
}

5: Create a controller to test localization:
Right-click on the Controllers folder and select "Add" -> "Controller" and select the "API Controller - Empty" template. Name it LocalizationTestController.
In LocalizationTestController, add the following code:
using LocalizationTest.Resources.Common; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
 
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LocalizationTestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<Errors> _localizer;
 
public LocalizationTestController(IStringLocalizer<Errors> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
 
[HttpGet("errors")]
    public IActionResult GetErrors()
    {
        var localizedString = _localizer["Hello"];
        return Ok(localizedString);
    }
}

6: After running it, you will get the following results:


I did exactly what you said but it only returns English language. {"name":"Hello","value":"Hello","resourceNotFound":true,"searchedLocation":"PakShavad6.Resources.Common.Errors"} Even with Content-Language header with fa-IR value, it does not return Persian language.

You are using the old Resource Explorer, which I didn't have a problem with, but I encountered this problem using the Revamped Resource Explorer.

I would like to know what you mean by Revamped Resource Explorer. Is it customized by you or caused by installing some plug-in? My Resource Explorer is the same window before and after the update. There is no change.

These changes have occurred in the new update of Visual Studio. From Version 17.11.0 onwards. I am currently using version 17.11.2 and the problem has not been resolved yet.

When I used an older VS version to create the project, everything worked fine, including the Resource Explorer window. After upgrading to the latest version, it still worked without issues. Resource Explorer window is also just like the old VS version. However, when creating a new project with the latest version, I noticed the Resource Explorer window had indeed changed, results returned matching the result you provided. This should be a bug after the version update. I saw you reported it on the VS Developer Community, there are many VS developers in DC. So please be patient for a response.
